# rendering 3D video/image for google cardboard

Tags: rendering

I'm looking to render out a video or image for display on Google Cardboard, i.e. a video is rendered with two barrel images, one for each eye, [side by side](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96FwizBOKSs).

[image]

I've found tutorials like the following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1S-AATilv84

But I know that Blender now has Multi-view rendering capability so was wondering how to render for Cardboard from Blender without rendering an image/video for each eye, which the [tutorial](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/multiview.html) tells you to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it!

Once you have set up your animation or single frame:

In your **Scene** tab enable **Views** and select **Stero 3D**

[image]

Select the Camera on the scene and go to the **Camera** tab. Sort out the **interocular disctance** this should be 0.06 = 6cm, the distance between your eyes. Set **Lens** to **Panoramic**

[image]

Go to the **Render** tab, change the **Dimensions** -> **Resolution** to be the resolution for a single eye (this will depend on the android phone you are using)

[image]

Again, in the **Render** tab scroll down to the **Output** and change the **Views Format** to be **Stereo 3D**. Set the **Stereo Mode** to be **Side-by-Side**.

[image]

Press **Render** or **Animation** depending on whether you are creating a single image or a video, and you should be done!

Check an example output here: https://youtu.be/fEFmGVymbUg (Which annoyingly youtube currently seems to be converting to different 3D formats!)

To render for VR, see this: http://b3d101.org/en/vr/

Comment: I can't find the "view" option in the scene tab. Is this something that has to be enabled somewhere?

Comment: You have to tick the box next to the name views. What version of blender are you running?

Comment: I'm on versoin 2.69.0.

Comment: I've tested this with 2.76, I'm not sure the feature is in versions below 2.74

Comment: Ah, then that would make sense. I'm on the Ubuntu repository version. I guess I should go get the lastest version. The repos are not as up-to-date as I'd like. Thanks for your fast response!

Comment: ubuntu is like that unfortunately, the app store versions are frozen at the release date of your ubuntu version.

Answer (score 1):

There is another set of options on the 'save as' dialog, and you need to set the 3D option and the side-by-side option there too.

See https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/multiview/usage.html for a lot more detail on this.

*I am copying what I said at [3D render - requested side-by-side but got anaglyphic - how to fix](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63025/3d-render-requested-side-by-side-but-got-anaglyphic-how-to-fix) to make it available more widely. This should be a comment but I don't have the reputation.*