# 3D render - requested side-by-side but got anaglyphic - how to fix

Tags: stereoscopy

I am trying to render a Blender image for Google Cardboard.

I followed the instructions in [rendering 3D video/image for google cardboard](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39190/rendering-3d-video-image-for-google-cardboard) with the default scene, but it gave me the image for coloured glasses, which I gather is called anaglyphic. I am using Blender 2.77a.

Does anyone know what I should do to fix my render?

Comment: Check if the stereo mode in output is set to **Side-by-Side**

Comment: @Denis, yes, using **side-by-side**. I've checked again, and I'm still getting anaglyphic.

Comment: @Denis Also, as the answer in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52139/how-do-i-use-blenders-built-in-stereoscopic-features?rq=1 points out, saving the image file creates two files, "_L" and "_R", with one image each.

Answer (score 2):

OK, The answer seems to be:

There is another set of options on the 'save as' dialog, and you need to set the 3D option and the side-by-side option there too.

See https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/multiview/usage.html for a lot more detail on this.