# What viewers apps are capable of interpreting blenders VR images? (And why won't stereo 3D save?)

Tags: stereoscopy

Let's say that I've used some of blenders render options like this:
[image]

To create two side by side images.  (Second question: whenever I choose "stereo 3D" (or squeeze frame?) **no image appears to be saved at all**, and if I try to save it manually, it just gives "left" and "right" images, I tried to .exr formats...)

So, now that I have generated these things, are there any apps really made in order to view them?  Specifically, I tried to do stero 3D by doing something like this:

[image]

So that the user could look around the field.
This is not a question about how to make these images "look right" this is a question about what pipelins exist to actually make this work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently blender only thinks stereo3D is valid for animations, for some reason, therby answering part of my own question.

Comment: By default, blender [does not write still images](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6772/34236). Stereo3D however is also an option for still images, but there's an [additional setting](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63274/34236) for the 3D format when you save the image. The answer to your other question seems to depend on your viewing device.